# Merge is not working on two dataframes of multi level index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

First DataFrame : housing, This data Frame contains MultiIndex (State, RegionName) and some relevant values in other 3 columns.

```
State           RegionName          2008q3          2009q2       Ratio  
New York         New York       499766.666667   465833.333333   1.072844
California      Los Angeles     469500.000000   413900.000000   1.134332
Illinois         Chicago        232000.000000   219700.000000   1.055985
Pennsylvania    Philadelphia    116933.333333   116166.666667   1.006600
Arizona           Phoenix       193766.666667   168233.333333   1.151773
```

Second DataFrame : list_of_university_towns, Contains the names of States and Some regions and has default numeric index

```
      State    RegionName
1   Alabama     Auburn
2   Alabama    Florence
3   Alabama   Jacksonville
4   Arizona    Phoenix  
5   Illinois   Chicago
```

Now the inner join of the two dataframes :

```
uniHousingData = pd.merge(list_of_university_towns,housing,how="inner",on=["State","RegionName"])
```

This gives no values in the resultant uniHousingData  dataframe, while it should have the bottom two values (index#4 and 5 from list_of_university_towns)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was space at the end of the string in the RegionName column of the second dataframe. used Strip() method to remove the space and it worked like a charm.